# how to update flag bit in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

This is my sql query,In `flag(00000)` every bit position   have different specification, e.g. `change 4th bit position to 1 when user is inactive`.**Here flag is varchar datatype(String).**

```
$sql="select flag from user where id =1"
```

**I got**

```
flag=10001 #it may be flag="00001" or flag="00101"
```

I want to update 2nd bit of this flag to 1.

```
$sql="update user set flag='-1---' where id=1" #it may be flag='11001' or flag='01001' or flag='01110'
```

Actually,I want to to update 2nd bit of this flag to 1,but with out updating it like flag='11001'.I want to do some thing like this.

```
$sql="update user set flag='--change(flag,2bit,to1)--' where id =1" #this is wrong
```

What can I do for it , only using one sql query?Is it possible?

Comment: What datatype is `flag`? You're talking about it as if it's a binary number, but MySQL is displaying it like a string.

Comment: sorry, I updated by question.it is varchar type.

Comment: Why are you using a varchar for binary data?

Comment: Actually, In flag(00000) every bit position have different specification i.e. change 4th bit position to 1 when user is inactive.

Comment: I understand what bit masks are used for. I just don't understand why you're doing it with a varchar instead of an integer. MySQL also has a `SET` datatype that lets you refer to the bits using names.

Comment: if I take flag as integer then 00001 will be 1 in db,then I will not able to update 4 bit to 1.

Comment: Sure you can. `set flag = flag | 1<<3`.

Comment: Great , I will try this for sure . Then get back to you :-)

Comment: @Barmar it is not working when I set  flag = flag | 1<<3. Getting flag =8.

Comment: 8 is the decimal value of binary 1000. If you want to see it in binary, use `select bin(flag)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update user
set flag = lpad(conv((conv(flag, 2, 10) | 1 << 3), 10, 2), 5, '0')
where id = 1
```

- `conv(flag, 2, 10)` converts the flag string from binary to decimal.
- `1 << 3` shifts a 1 bit 3 binary places to the left
- `|` performs a binary OR of this, to set that bit. This arithmetic operation will automatically coerce the decimal string to a number; you can use an explicit `CAST` if you prefer.
- `conv(..., 10, 2)` will convert the decimal string back to a binary string
- `lpad(..., 5, '0')` adds leading zeroes to make the string 5 characters long

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f5ac8/1)

To set the bit to 0, you use:

```
set flag = lpad(conv((conv(flag, 2, 10) & ~(1 << 3)), 10, 2), 5, '0')
```

Comment: thanks for response,Actually it will only work when my flag is 10000 type.It will not work when my flag is 00001 type.I have change my question. In my user table flag is STRING TYPE(VARCHAR).

Comment: I updated it to use `LPAD()` to get leading zeroes, I guess that's what you're saying doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it is working, but if I want to set some 1 bit to 0, it is not working.

Comment: Added the code to set the bit to 0. This is basic bit manipulation.

Comment: Bravo ;-) thanks @barmar . this is the Best Answer,I got for this.

Comment: Testing whether a bit is set is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

you want to use the bitwise or operator `|`

```
update user set flag = flag | (1 << 1) where id =1
```

if flag was 101 flag will now be 111

if flag was 000 flag will now be 010

1 << 1 shifts 1 up one bit - making it 10 (binary 2)

edit - not tested but use

```
update user set flag = cast(cast(flag AS SIGNED) | (1 << 1) AS CHAR) where id =1
```

Comment: flag  is varchar type. It is not integer type

Comment: Yes tested now - @Barmar's conv (flag,2,10) is the way to properly convert

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a VARCHAR, you are better off using string manipulation functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

```
UPDATE user
SET flag = CONCAT(LEFT(flag, 1), '1', RIGHT(flag, 3))
WHERE id = 1
```

However, you probably want to convert this field to an INT so that you can use the bit functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

Comment: MySQL uses `CONCAT()` for concatenation, not `+`.

Comment: Updated. My comment still stands - you should either use string functions, or convert the field to an INT. I recommend the latter.